# Configure spring cloud config server for each profile group

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-profiles

I have few environments. There are:

- local
- dev
- test
- qa
- lod
- prod

Everything clear if config server connects to all of them.

In my case I need configuration server per group:

- under dev control
- under qa control
- near devops control

Groups are connected to permissions and different environments.

so I need for each client something like:

**bootstrap.yml**

```
# default configs for local, dev, test profiles
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://local-dev-test-configuration-server:8888

---
# **bootstrap-qa.yml**
spring:
  profiles: qa
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://qa-configuration-server:8888

---
# **bootstrap-prod.yml**
spring:
  profiles: prod,lod
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://lod-prod-configuration-server:8888
```

Where

- `local-dev-test-configuration-server` would have access to `local`, `dev` and `test` server configurations;
- `qa-configuration-server` would have access to `qa` configuration;
- `lod-prod-configuration-server` would have access to `prod` and `lod` configurations only.

### Question:

I researched spring boot documentation but I have not faced with `bootstrap.yml` profiling.

1. Which way I should follow to cover my needs (manage 3 different config servers and correspond profiles)?
2. I've detected ability to [configure different git resources](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_pattern_matching_and_multiple_repositories) for same config server. Is this approach the best for my case (I also have to manage few repositories to keep required configs)? I do not think so. I need to have few config servers for different envs because of different visibility. Thus I need configure on each consumer config hostname depending profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to configure clients for spring-cloud-configuration-servers:

1. spring-boot supports profiles in `bootstrap.yml`, so configuration provided in question can be used as solution

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://local-dev-test-configuration-server:8888
---
spring:
  profiles: qa
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://qa-configuration-server:8888

---
spring:
  profiles: prod,lod
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://lod-prod-configuration-server:8888
```

2. In case you want to keep `bootstrap.yml` configuration as simple as it possible:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://local-dev-test-configuration-server:8888
```

in this case solution is to use `-Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888` parameter overrides required property for example:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=localhost -Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888 -jar ./target/discovery-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

### P.S.

Approaches can be mixed.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer, @Sergi. Had a follow up question; where does the "bootstrap.yml" go exactly? Does it reside on the the Config Server? or on one of the theoretical clients? Also - do these distinct configuration ymls need to reside on unique config servers?